# Python pandas verification block text with rule

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do text verification. I have to verify the candidate of block text belongs to content or non content.

The input for this program is csv file.

[image]

The candidate column is shown the the sequence number of candidates text block.

So the line number 82-87 is one text block, 111-116 is the other text block, 1552-1553 is the othre one and so on. And i want to do check each candiddate text block and if candidate fullfil one of the rules then will be used as the output.

Rules for verification the candidate of text block  are:

1. The candiate must be contain h1 and The number of TC column must be > 0 and the LTC column must be < 0.
2. the number of TC in text block must be more than Threshold TC

The number of TC in text block means the sum of TC in a thext block. for example in candidate 0, number of TC is 0+1+5+7+4+0 = 17.

The threshold TC is 30

If candidate fullfils one of those rules it will be used as the output. 
And then I just want present the column words from text block as the output and will be save in txt.

So based on the rule, the output will be the candidate number 0 and 5.

My expected output like

[image]

UPDATE MY PROGRAM

```
import pandas as pd
from listTV import get_filepaths_tv

filenames = get_filepaths_tv(r"C:\Users\firlyarmanda\PycharmProjects\EkstraksiBerita\TC_0.1.5")
index = 0
for f in filenames:
    file_html=open(str(f),"r")
    dataf = pd.read_csv(file_html)
    df = dataf.dropna() #menghilangkan kolom NaN

    candidate_groups = df.groupby('candidate')


#f = open('textfile.txt', 'w')
    for _, group_df in candidate_groups:
        if group_df['TC'].sum() > 40 or (group_df['TAG'] == "['h1']").any() and (group_df['LTC'] == 0).all():
            a = '\n'.join(group_df['Words'].astype(str)) + '\n'

    #f.write('\n'.join(group_df['Words'].astype(str)) + '\n')
    #f.close()
            index += 1
            stored_file = "textverification/" + '{0:03}'.format(index) + ".txt"
            filewrite = open(stored_file, "w")
            filewrite.write(a)
            filewrite.close
```

But i got the output separately. I want to join all the output and save to text.

Comment: it works but i got the output separately because i write the print group_df['Words'] for each rules. But its not the output i expected. i want join the output

Comment: Then as I suggested in my answer, try this: `print '\n'.join(group_df['Words'])`. Or this, to separate with space: `print ' '.join(group_df['Words'])`

Comment: Im getting this error TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, float found. when i join the df['words']

Comment: OK so you have floats in `group_df['Words']`, which is also why my answer does not work. Then try: `print '\n'.join(group_df['Words'].astype(str))`.

Comment: where i have to put the print '\n'.join(group_df['Words'].astype(str))? because if i put it in same indent with if , i got All the candidate not the candidate that fullfill the condition. and if i put it in same indent with for, i got the wrong candidate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133903/discussion-between-kim-hyesung-and-ians).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what your rules are precisely, but you can use `groupby`'s filter method. First, define a function that checks if a group satisfies the conditions:

```
def rules(group):
    return (group['HTML'].str.contains('<h1>').any() and 
            group['TC'].sum() > 0 and 
            group['LTC'].sum() <= 0)
```

Then filter the dataframe:

```
result = df.groupby('candidate').filter(rules)
```

Lastly it's not clear how you want to print the text of selected candidates, but you can get the text of each candidate like this:

```
result.groupby('candidate')['Words'].apply(lambda w: '\n'.join(w))
```

This will join all the words in the `'Words'` column by the newline character `'\n'`.

---

**Edit**: After discussion, here is what worked for the asker (which includes some code provided in the other answer by [user3712352](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41808740/5276797)).

```
candidate_groups = df.groupby('candidate')

f = open('textfile.txt', 'w')

for _, group_df in candidate_groups:
    if group_df['TC'].sum() > 30 and (group_df['TAG'] == "['h1']").any() and (group_df['LTC'] == 0).all():
        f.write('\n'.join(group_df['Words'].astype(str)) + '\n')

f.close()
```

Comment: i got error like ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). I updated my program but i have problem with how to join the output.

Comment: My bad, I fixed the code by adding `.any()` so the result is a boolean. Can you check again?

Comment: it still does not work i got TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, float found

Answer (score 2):

After loading the csv:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(INPUT_FILE)
```

A good start for this task would be grouping candidates' rows:

```
candidate_groups = df.groupby('candidate')
```

Then you can iterate over candidates and test the requirements:

```
def print_x(x):
    print x

for _, group_df in candidate_groups:
    if group_df['TC'].sum() > 30: # 30 is the threshold
        if group_df[(group_df['TAG'] == "['h1']") & (group_df['LTC'] < 0) & (group_df['TC'] > 0)].shape[0] > 0:
            group_df['Words'].apply(print_x) #print word
```

Comment: i got error invalid syntax group_df['Words'].apply(lambda x: print(x))

Comment: My bad. It is not possible to use print inside a lambda expression.
I edited my response